# nginx stopped listening after restarting

Tags: nginx, debian

I was able to make Nginx run on my Debian 7.7 system using all the default configuration (I didn't touch anything after the installation). I was able to access it by accessing my server's IP.

When I run netstat -altpn, I can see that nginx is listening to 127.0.0.1:80

Now, I need to create a new configuration for a new site so I created a copy of the config

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/example
```

I changed the following lines:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    to
root /var/www/example;

===================================

server_name localhost;
    to
server_name local.example.com
```

after these changes, I created a shortcut to sites-enabled:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example
```

I then restarted nginx by issuing:

```
service nginx restart
```

When I refreshed my browser, I can no longer see the page.

When I issued **netstat -altpn** nginx is no longer in the list.

What could I have done wrong? I spent almost two days just making nginx to work.

Comment: Any entry on nginx `error.log`?

Comment: Running `nginx -t` will tell you what mistake you've made with your config file.

Comment: error.log is empty and nginx-t is saying "test is successful"

Comment: What is your complete virtual host configuration?

Comment: You miss a `;` at the end of the `server_name` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work by following this advice:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021481/nginx-not-listening-to-port-80#comment28970877_19084424

As it turns out, it's very important to indicate the full path for BOTH parameters when creating the symlink.

Comment: so... the question was "how can I create a symlink?" your conclusion is false btw.

Comment: Nope. The question was correct. The answer is just strange. If you read the link I posted, the OP and I are having the same problem and creating the symlink in that manner is what makes it work.

Comment: The same problem creating a symlink....